# Ktor database insert

Tags: mysql, kotlin

My task is to insert values to database (MySql)

I made connection with db but when inserting values i cannot input more values than 2.

```
 database.insert(ClientEntity){
            set (it.id, "Mike", 26 )
        }
```

My ClientEntity has id, name, age.
But set has only 2 input fields.

Error when using setOf:

Edit:

```
database.insert(ClientEntity){
        set (it.id, 1 )
        **set**(it.name, "mike")
        set(it.age, 25)
    }
```

> Field 'name' doesn't have a default value

Comment: Can you ALTER the table to set a default value for the "name" field you are trying to change?

Comment: I can but i only want to add id, name and age. For now there is nothing in table.

Comment: Well the error is due to it expecting data from you in the "name" field but it isn't getting it so its passing an Empty or Null, and since the table doesn't have a default value, it doesn't know how to handle that and throws this error.

Comment: In MYSQL  - you can INSERT a new record, but if you want to "insert more into that new record" you have to UPDATE the record instead of INSERT.

Comment: I edited post, problem is with set name, I get error:  None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Comment: There was something in ClientEntity. I used varchar but when I wrote it.name in insert function .name was of type Any so that was the problem.

Comment: Thanks for responding back!  That makes sense.  I find that 9 out 10 times its always a datatype issue, and the 1 out of 10 is a self induced typo.

Comment: When you get time you might copy your answer from the comment and make an answer, and mark your own answer as the solution in case someone else has this problem.